# changing directories of android projects and svn

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I have two projects sitting in our SVN repository that are android apps. the second is based on the first, and was split off it some time ago. for example purposes, we will say the first app is called "phone app" and the second is called "tablet app"

they are stored on the svn server at the locations

`http://server.com/svn/mobile-apps/phoneapp`

`http://server.com/svn/mobile-apps/tabletapp`

that works fine, and we can check them out from svn in eclipse.

the problem is when importing the code as an android project.

the first app, the original app, gets stored at 
`c:\workspace\mobile-apps\phoneapp\`

but the second app, since it's a copy, stores at
`c:\workspace\mobile-apps\phoneapp (1)\`

i realize this is probably a setting in the `tabletapp` application, it wasn't changed and so it's trying to save to `phoneapp`, eclipse see's that the folder already contains a project, and so it defaults to `phoneapp (1)` for the directory.

my question is, where exactly is this setting? i've checked throughout the project and cannot for the life of me find it. i thought refactoring would do it, but that never seemed to have any effect on the folder structure (it did change the name of the application fine)

Comment: It is because the project name is same for both the projects. Refactor it in eclipse

Comment: @intrepidkarthi i mentioned in the last line, we have done a refactor and that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Eclipse won't detect the same project name unless you are specifying it. Check in your .classpath file also.

Comment: Hi! Even if you refactor in Eclipse, there is a file called .project which contains among other things the name of the project. I don't think Eclipse changes it, even if you do the refactoring.